# rails/pry very weird keyboard typed chars different in response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, pry

In RoR environment and debug with pry-rails and unicorn workers running.

Occasionally I had issues with binding, and can't exit when type exit or anything, it response back with quite random order of chars that had been typed.

(I suspected that maybe the multiple unicorn workers that picked up the typed chars randomly, causing this effect.)

How did this happened? and how to fix it? 
I typed "exit" severally times, see 1) the echo text being out of order and 2) actual command used in response is different in command line as well.

```
[1] pry(#<ReportsController>)> xtei>)> exit
NameError: undefined local variable or method `xtei' for #<ReportsController:0x007f9f71631470>
from (pry):1:in `table_filter_dates_store'
[9] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>>)> xtei
NameError: undefined local variable or method `xtei' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>:0x007f9f7283f518>
from (pry):14:in `_app_views_base__data_html_erb__1997450648765874917_70161408871120'
[10] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>>)> eiit
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ei' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>:0x007f9f7283f518>
from (pry):15:in `_app_views_base__data_html_erb__1997450648765874917_70161408871120'
[11] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>>)> eiit
NameError: undefined local variable or method `ei' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>:0x007f9f7283f518>
from (pry):16:in `_app_views_base__data_html_erb__1997450648765874917_70161408871120'
[2] pry(#<ReportsController>)> xtxtxtei exit
NameError: undefined local variable or method `xtxtxtei' for #<ReportsController:0x007f9f71631470>
from (pry):2:in `table_filter_dates_store'
[12] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>>)> xtei
NameError: undefined local variable or method `xtei' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>:0x007f9f7283f518>
from (pry):17:in `_app_views_base__data_html_erb__1997450648765874917_70161408871120'
[3] pry(#<ReportsController>)> xtx8>>)> exit
NameError: undefined local variable or method `xtx' for #<ReportsController:0x007f9f71631470>
from (pry):3:in `table_filter_dates_store'
[13] pry(#<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>>)> eitei
NameError: undefined local variable or method `eitei' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f72839f28>:0x007f9f7283f518>
from (pry):18:in `_app_views_base__data_html_erb__1997450648765874917_70161408871120'
```

Comment: Are you running a process runner, such as `guard`? I had a similar thing happen, I thought `guard` and `pry` are competing for keyboard input. Also, if multiple workers all triggered pry, it might be like this, I believe. Pure speculation, though.

Comment: Thanks, I do use several `guard` gems, such as `guard-rails` `guard-bundler`, yes, that might be the issue. My temporally solutions was simply limited to 1 worker, and start `sidekiq` in another window, instead `foreman start`.